# Github Action Unity Build Automation, cant run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, github-actions, build-automation

Always got this result on running gitlab actions for building unity

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vE0c.png)

it is not that its error actually, just stopped on progress, i've tried on my device with exact script also in TeamCity, it is works but not in github actions

I using my own device

```
name: UnityBuild-Automation

# Controls when the workflow will run
on: workflow_dispatch



# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: Windows
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Remove Cache Build
        run: |
            $Folder = '.\Builds'
            If(Test-Path -Path $Folder) {Remove-Item –path $Folder -include * –recurse}

      #always stopped in the middle of process here
      - name: Run a Build
        run: Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.3f1/Editor/Unity.exe" -ArgumentList "-xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args='-screen 0 640x480x24' unity-editor -projectPath='.' -quit -batchmode -nographics -executeMethod SuperUnityBuild.BuildTool.BuildCLI.PerformBuild"
        
      - name: Export
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: Build-Result
          path: Builds/*
```

Comment: This isn't about [tag:unityscript] as that version of unity doesn't support it. It's about [tag:c#] if anything.